# AJAX, obtener los datos devueltos mediante la peticion POST en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario con cuatro selects, los selects envian datos mediante método POST a una página llamada prices.php, una vez ahí, se calculo unos precios y se devuelve un entero indicando el precio.

La cosa, es que me gustaría mostrar el resultado dentro de un DIV en el Index de la página, y no tengo conocimientos de AJAX, lo usé hace bastante tiempo, pero ahora ni la menor idea.

Tengo lo siguiente:

Index.php

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"> </script>
 <script>

    $(function)(){
      $("#btn-enviar").click(function()){
        var url = "prices.php";
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: $("#form").serialize(),
          success: function(data)
          {
            $("#contenedor").html(data);
          }
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>


<form method="post" id="form">
    <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" name="Objetos" required>
      <option value="Casa">Casa</option>
      <option value="Coche">Coche</option>
      <option value="Caramelo">Caramelo</option>
      <option value="Caña">Caña</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" id="btn-enviar" value="Prices" style="width:100%" />
</form>

<div id="contenedor"> </div>
```

En la página de prices.php tengo un case, evaluando la respuesta que se pasa y devolviendo con un echo su precio.

Sin embargo, cuando hago click sobre el botón, solo consigo que la página index se refresque.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias de antemano.

Update:

> fallado la carga del  con origen
>   "http://localhost/Something/P%C3%A1gina/jquery-3.3.1.min.js".
>   Página:103:1 SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters )

Update:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes cambiar al botón el tipo por type="button" e indicarme si cuando des click aparece algún error en la consola?

Comment: @PedroE.Palau Hola, acutalizo con el mensaje de error.

Comment: El error que pones, no tiene nada que ver con el código, debe ser que hay algun script de jquery que se está cargando mal. Puedes compartir todo el código o al menos verificar donde cargas el scrip jquery-3.3.1.min.js?

Comment: El código está perfecto para que funcione, no importa que apliques o no el event.preventDefault() porque el Ajax es asincrónico, te propongo que revises toda la página en busca del script que menciona el error.

Comment: Buenas otra vez, @PedroE.Palau, el js lo tenia en otra carpeta, ahora lo tengo montado en la misma, y el js funciona, el error que me da (el que comentas) esta en la linia 107, que corresponde con este apartado:     $(function)(){, se queja de que falta un parentesis... pero no encuentro el error.

Comment: Correcto, se te fue un cierre de paréntesis aquí: function) quítale ese paréntesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes arreglar la siguiente línea:

`$(function)(){`

por:

`$(function(){`

El error está en que se te pasó un cierre de paréntesis `)` a continuación de `function)`

## Código

```
$(function() {
  $("#btn-enviar").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "prices.php";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $("#form").serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $("#contenedor").html(data);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Disculpa las molestias, ahora en la siguiente linea se queja de la llave.
$("#btn-enviar").click(function(e)){

Comment: Es el mismo error, si te fijas tienes otro cierre luego de )). Editaré la respuesta para que tengas la función correcta.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, ahora en la consola no genera ningún error, lamento las molestias, sin embargo, al dar click, la consola me devuelve esto. TypeError: $.ajax is not a function[Saber más] Página:111:7
<anónimo>
http://localhost/Something/Página/:111:7
dispatch
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:41912
add/v.handle
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:39966

Comment: Estimado, es porque estás usando la versión slim de jQuery, que solo tiene lo básico. Debes usar la versión completa de jQuery para acceder a funciones ajax.

Comment: De verdad que lo siento... He probado con esta; https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js ¿Se supone que esta es la completa, verdad? el error sigue siendo el mismo. Perdona las molestias, de verdad...

Comment: Es porque tienes un jquery.slim cargándose en tu página, debes eliminarla de la página, tienes 2 jquery. Verifica que tengas uno solo y sea el regular.

Comment: En estos momentos el unico jquery que tengo, es el que mencioné arriba, el anterior lo había eliminado, y es el que estoy cargando desde el script

Comment: Vale, tienes toda la razón del mundo, había otro script furulando por ahi abajo, ahora si funciona perfecmante, lamento de verás todo este marrón, muchiiiiiiisimas gracias, de verdad.

Comment: Te comento que ese error es cuando usas la versión slim de jQuery, si ya lo eliminaste prueba actualizando la caché de tu navegador, en caso de que no funcione por favor comparte el código completo tu página para echarle un ojo. Pero básicamente el error nuevo sobre el ajax es por el uso del jQuery slim.

Comment: Yep, como te comenté arriba, habia un jquery por abajo furulando en la versión slim, ya está solucionado, lamento las molestias de verdad. :)

Comment: Por alguna razón la peticion post me llega vacia al php, ¿a qué se debe?

Comment: No debería suceder, me puedes verificar en la consola si no hay algún error y de paso verifica si envía los datos correctos en el Request Headers cuando revisas la pestaña Network de la consola en Chrome.

Comment: Usa esta variante: $.post(url, $("#form").serialize(), function(data) { $("#contenedor").html(data); });

Comment: Te adjunto una imagen con lo que me pides, he probado cambiando $.ajax por lo que me dijiste y el resultado sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: Solo me queda pensar en algún error de Cross-Domain o algo similar, la verdad es algo raro, existe una pregunta similar a esta nueva que haces en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650516/jquery-ajax-method-post-but-post-empty

Comment: Son 4 selects, es posible que el numero de selects influya? Ya que leí sobre la funcion SerializeArry, he probado con esa y nada...

Answer (score 2):

Intenta agregar esto en tu handler:

```
$("#btn-enviar").click(function(e)){
    e.preventDefault();
```

Y en tu HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="form" onSubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: Hola!, he intentado como me has dicho, el refresco ha desaparecido, ahora en su lugar esta el pequeño update intentando traer los datos (presumo), sin embargo, no trae nada

Comment: Ya edite.  Intentalo

Comment: Buenas, he probado con lo que me has dicho, ahora ni siquiera se ve el update, pero sigo sin obternet datos, (la página princes.php funciona perfectamente, lo he mirado varias veces, ¿qué puede ser que esté haciendo mal?)

Answer (score 0):

Fue hace mucho pero si a alguien le sirve yo hago esto:

```
async function pintarUnProducto(idProducto){
    await $.ajax({
       url: "/producto/pintar_uno_ajax", //aca prueben la url, servicio o lo que sea
            data: {
                'id': idProducto, // si necesitan parametros pueden mandarlos asi
            },
            type: 'POST',
            error: function(err) {
            Toast.fire({ icon:'success', title: err })
       },
       success: function(data) {
       // les lanza un alert de lo que contiene la url
       alert(data);
       // $("#productos").append(data); si reciben html pueden insertarlo en un div con el id productos
       },
       complete: function() {}
   })
}
```

Ese código me funciona para una peticiones `get` y `post` del lado del servidor he usado php y symfony retornando HTML, JSON O SIMPLES DATOS.